# how to converter unreadable block of code in a class

Tags: c#, unicode

i recently bumped to a block of code which are literally being consumed by a set of what seems to be unicode representations. i tried google-ing for possible fixes on how i can correct this or revert them to a its readable - state to therefore be able to compile the parent solution, but i have been not given any luck. does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue ?

```
using System;

public class \u001E\u001F\u0001\u0005\u0002
{
    public \u001E\u001F\u0001\u0005\u0002()
    {
        this.\u001E\u001F\u0001\u000551\u0006 = \u001E\u001F\u0001\u000550\u0006.\u001E\u001F\u0001\u000552\u0006;
    }

    public \u001E\u001F\u0001\u000550\u0006 \u001E\u001F\u0001\u000551\u0006;
}
```

Comment: These are all just identifiers, it doesn´t matter how they are called. Basically its just the name of a class and a call to one of its members.

Comment: If you got that code by decompiling third party library - it was obfuscated to prevent you from extracting meaning from the code.

Comment: This is not valid C# code -- the Unicode code points in such identifiers used must fall in specific categories, which exclude control characters like `\u001e`. IL code has no such restriction. This is the output of a decompiler trying to turn an obfuscated assembly into C#, but failing. In other words, the obfuscation is doing exactly what the developers intended it to do. There is no "fix" for this, other than to get code that *is* intended to be reused. I suppose if you *really* wanted to you could write a renaming tool that works on the IL level (i.e. a better decompiler).